# What are the Python style guidelines on nested parentheses for functions?

Tags: javascript

trying to remove myself from this site, so I am knowingly filling up the post with junk content. I would appreciate the prior content not being restored. -OP

Comment: Something that's readable.  `f(g(x))` is fine; something like `do_complicated_stuff(create_trained_unicorns(dragonEggs))` can be confusing.

Comment: Thanks. The best answer would be a reference to an authoritative document (PEP, something Guido said, popular reference book).

Comment: You're missing a `)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`PEP20`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says about it:

```
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
```

To follow this, extract the function calls:

```
parentheses_result = parenthesis()
nested_result = nested(parentheses_result)
using_result = using(nested_result)
function(using_result)
```

But, this should be taken with a little grain of salt. Sometimes, as @uʍop ǝpısdn mentioned, it is okay to nest function calls. The choice would depend on how readable, understandable it would be without keeping function call results in intermediate variables.

Comment: As written, the code will fail... `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'parentheses' referenced before assignment`

Comment: -1 This is taking it **way too far**, in my opinion. Using several variables that have absolutely no purpose or semantic meaning other than unfolding a line is a resource, but not the norm.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn yup, it really depends, example is synthetic and the readability would depend on the functions used, names, parameters. Sometimes it is okay to nest calls, I understand.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn added a note, good point raised, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The real question is: are the intermediate values meaningful? In a sequence of calls `f(g(h(x))`, are `h(x)` or `g(...)` valuable objects on their own, deserving a name?

When they are, you may want to unfold the calls into variable assignments:

```
request = http.get(url)
bar(request)
return foo(request)
```

When they aren't, keep them in the same line:

```
x = double(square(sum(numbers))
```